# Need some help for this case. (Sed or Awk)

Tags: awk, sed

I have some string like

```
./os/example-ubuntu-14.04"
```

I wanna keep string

```
example-ubuntu-14.04
```

remove **"./os/"**. 
Can I use sed or awk for this case.

Thanks

Comment: `sed` is the tool for the job. Just use the normal substitution form, locate the line and replace `./os/` with nothing. (e.g. `sed 's:./os/::'`)

Comment: It 's output of "find . -type l -ls" command
Output like below
18883442      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 xxx   xxx         20 Th11 13 11:44 ./os/sample-ubuntu-14.04 -> sameple2-ubuntu-14.04

Comment: It work with (sed 's:./os/::')
Thanks you so much

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica `\.` ?

Comment: Ooof. -- @jhnc -- right you are. You should escape the `'.'` with either `\.` or just `[.]`. Without the escape the `'.'` matches any character.. Better `sed 's:^[.]/os/::'`

Comment: JFYI If you have the string stored in a variable, e.g. "str", you can say `${str##*/}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just

```
echo "./os/example-ubuntu-14.04" | cut -c 6-
example-ubuntu-14.04
```

Which will basically remove first 6 characters from beginning of the string

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are looking for is implemented with the `basename` utility. While you can use sed/cut, those tools are more generic, and will cover any filename.

```
basename "./os/example-ubuntu-14.04"
```

Assuming that you are writing some shell script, you can use the built-in functionality

```
P="./os/example-ubuntu-14.04"
echo ${P##*/}
```

Which will remove anything until the last '/'